# Why CSS3 perspective transform is not working in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I am trying to create a css transform for dropdown menu, but it does not work in firefox, this is the  css code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes flipInX {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes flipInX {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.flipInX {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
  -ms-backface-visibility: visible !important;
  backface-visibility: visible !important;
  -webkit-animation-name: flipInX;
  animation-name: flipInX;
}
```

so is there special code for firefox transformation?
what is messing?

Comment: you forgot to add `-moz-` prefix

Answer (score 0):

check this fiddle and see if it works for you.
http://jsfiddle.net/jybenjya/

it works fine for me. but the only thing you need to change is to add a time to the animation, either by adding "animation-duration:" or changing 'animation-name' to 'animation' and adding the time on the end as below

```
-webkit-animation: flipInX 3s;
animation: flipInX 3s;
```

just to be safe i usually include all the prefixes (moz for firefox)

```
  -webkit-animation: flipInX 3s;
     -moz-animation: flipInX 3s;
       -o-animation: flipInX 3s;
          animation: flipInX 3s;

-webkit-transform:
   -moz-transform:
    -ms-transform:
     -o-transform:
        transform:
```

etc.. but in my jsfiddle i didn't seem to need to include them.

Answer (score 0):

Some configurations of Linux and older Windows machines (those without `WebGL` support) have trouble with 3D transforms and will treat them as if perspective was set as `none`.

Firefox on Windows **incorrectly** [renders plugin content within no-op 3D transforms](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1048279).